# make jetty-maven-plugin use existing jetty configuration directory?

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I want to use the jetty-maven-plugin for debugging reasons.  I want to plug it into our current code base with as little effort as possible.

Currently our codebase includes a conf folder for jetty files, and an install script that will configure a jetty environment to be run.

Is there a convenient way to tell the maven plugin to look at my jetty directory and just use it, meaning loading the xml files fron /etc, running the start.ini, and saving log/error messages into the jetty outputs.

Failing that is there simply an easy way to say to use all the configuraiton files in a conf folder, without having to spell out each one individually within the jettyXml configuration option?